# Custom Routing with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, namespaces, asp.net-web-api

Suppose that I have a nested *one to many*-type hierarchy database as follows:

One **Region** has many **Countries**; each **Country** has many **Cities**; a **City** must belong to *one and only one* country.

Abstracting this information into a RDBMS is a trivial exercise, but (to my mind) the most sensible REST endpoint to return a list of countries for a **given region id** would be something like the following:

```
HTTP GET http://localhost/Region/3/Countries
```

By default, the .NET Web API's routing would be, at best, `http://localhost/Countries/Region/3` or `http://localhost/Region/Countries/3`.

Is there a sensible naming-convention I should follow, or is the routing customisable enough to allow URIs to take any shape I like?

Comment: I suppose I should add that I'm working with an existing DBMS and want to build public/private APIs to the datastore.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The routing should be customizable enough to get the URLs you're looking for. Assuming you want URLs in the form 'http://localhost/Region/3/Countries', you could register this custom route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("MyRoute", "Region/{regionId}/Countries", new { controller = "Region", action = "GetCountries" });
```

This would dispatch requests to the 'GetCountries' action on the 'RegionController' class. You can have a regionId parameter on the action that gets model bound automatically for you from the URI.

You may want to look online for the attribute routing package for WebAPI since it may be more appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Routings should be quite flexible - the question would be how you'd like to serve the data. Do you have one controller in mind or multiple?

If you had a RegionController I don't see why you couldn't configure a route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CountryList",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{regionId}/countries"
);
```

And a corresponding method:

```
public CountryCollection Get(int regionId)
```

Or am I missing something in your question? Where does your default routing come from?

Have a look at their documentation:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api