# Does adding custom routes to WEB API make it non-REST?

Tags: rest, soap, asp.net-web-api

quick question - I was reading about RESTful services yesterday and someone had asked why SOAP wasn't RESTful. The answer was that SOAP doesn't have the 'generality of interfaces' property as is required by REST.

Then it struck me that I had been adding custom routes to my Web API like so: 
[Custom Routing with ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339046/custom-routing-with-asp-net-web-api)

By doing that - I made my web API non-generic, thereby making the service non-RESTful, right? Not that that's a big deal, I just want to know whether I grasped the concepts correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the rest rqeuires you to identify resoruces alone, not actions on them.
For example you might have an action addComment on Person, your route being

`POST persons/2/addComment`
This would make it non restful. The ideal way to do this would be: 
`POST persons/2/comments`
For deleting a comment `DELETE persons/2/comments/{commebntid}`

So if you vary from this, your service becomes non restful. Its pretty hard to make a completely restful interface.
For example, if  you have an object account, that you directly increment or decrement balance
`accounts/2`. You might have withdraw and deposit actions. `POST accoints/2/withdraw`. In rest, you need to either pass the balance as a parameter after decrementing it (PUT). There may be cases where you donot want to do this. You might not want to let the world know the balance of the user. Then you cant easily use put. You'd have to create a new entity: `transaction` and create transactions and calculate the account balance on the basis of transactions.

Ther eis no such thing as a generic API. You can't use amazons api and facebooks api interchangibly since the entities and operations are different. Don't worry too much about generalization. Just understand what the RESTful way is, and see if you can implemen it. If you have to tweak around it a bit, that's fine

Comment: Thanks, we're on the same page. I have something like /timetable/getTimeTable - thus non-restful.

Comment: @spike I thoroughly recommend reading the RESTful Services Cookbook - it helps you to decide on which approach to take, while identifying the various trade-offs: http://www.amazon.co.uk/RESTful-Services-Cookbook-Subbu-Allamaraju/dp/0596801688/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1382528170&sr=8-1&keywords=rest+cookbook